# Can't get Google App Engine Images API get_serving_url function to work

Tags: google-app-engine, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I'm new to Google App Engine and Python.  I've almost completed a project, but can't get the get_serving_url() function to work.  I've stripped everything down to the most basic functionality, following the documentation. And yet I still get a 500 error from the server.  Any thoughts?  Here is the code:

```
from google.appengine.api import images

....

class Team(db.Model):
    avatar = db.BlobProperty()

    ....

    def to_dict(self):
        ....
        image_url = images.get_serving_url(self.avatar.key())
```

The last line is the problem...commenting it out makes the app run fine.  But it is copied almost directly from the documentation.  I should note that I can download the avatar blob directly with:

```
class GetTeamAvatar(webapp2.RequestHandler):
def post(self):
    team_id = self.request.get('team_id')
    team = Team.get_by_id(long(team_id))
    self.response.write(team.avatar)
```

So I know it is stored correctly.  I do not have PIL on my machine...is that the issue?  The datastore's image API says it has PIL locally so if I'm deploying my app it shouldn't matter, right?  I have Python 3.3 and apparently PIL stopped at 2.6.

Answer (score 2):

Python appengine run time is 2.7, (OK and 2.5) so don't even try to work with 3.x.

Secondly get_serving_URL is a method you call with a BlobStore entity key not a BlobProperty.

You are confusing two different things here.

I would concentrate on getting your code to run locally correctly under 2.7 first, and PIL is available for 2.7.

Answer (score 0):

I'm very impressed if you're trying to deploy your app without even testing it locally.

One thing you'll need to do is make PIL available in your app.yaml via the libraries attribute.